# Which is grammatically right?

Tags: grammaticality

> I remember you send me photo with her when she was just born

or

> I remember you've sent me photo with her when she was just born

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence uses **send** which is simple present. You are remembering something that happened in the past, and you can't use simple present to talk about something that happened in the past.

Your second sentence uses **have sent** which is present perfect: you can use this about something that happened in the past and is still happening, or something that happened in the past and had a lasting effect.

In this instance, what you want to emphasize is what you remember: the sending, which happened in the past. For this, you need to use past simple: **sent**.

In spoken english, we can omit **that** after verbs like **think**, **feel** and **say**, but we don't normally omit it in written English.

Normally, we talk about a photo **of** somebody or something. You might, however, say "... of you with her.."

Your sentence should therefore be:

> I remember that you sent me a photo of her when she was just born